# How to remove non english chars from a string

Tags: shell-script, string

I have a BASH script I wrote that removes META data off mp3 (etc) then I chop them up to reform them if needed resample the mp3 and reasign the data to make a directory to corraspond to artist / album ...

I got a hold of some mp3's that have non english chars in the middle of the song title. I need to know the best way to remove that middle part leaving both ends of the sting put back together to the title of the song. using exiftool I strip the META data off giving me this output placed into the var-name

```
 ARTIST1="`exiftool -Artist "$FILENAME" -p '$Artist'`"
 TITLE1="`exiftool -Title  "$FILENAME" -p '$Title'`"
 ALBUM1="`exiftool -Album  "$FILENAME" -p '$Album'`"


first strip... Artist is -> The Stranglers and Friends
first strip... Album is -> Live in
first strip... Title is -> The Raven ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã¢â‚¬Å“ With Basil Gabbi
```

song title in META Data

The Raven  ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã¢â‚¬Å“ With Basil Gabbi

how would I strip what is between the META data song name to get this instead?

```
The Raven With Basil Gabbi
```

where the syntext would look something like this

```
 newSongName="$( what ever code goes here to strip out that non english sting part )"
```

so I can write the new string back into the file replacing the old META data with the new string.

Thanks

Comment: Please remember to accept answers that have solved your problem. You have asked 18 questions and have only accepted 2 answers.

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string with garbble in it ->

```
 $ x="The Raven Æ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã¢â‚¬Å“ With Basil Gabbi"
```

this keeps hold of all caps and lower case a-z removes everything else

```
$ echo ${x//[^A-Za-z ]/}
```

Leaving the string like this

```
The Raven With Basil Gabbi
```

would look like this in the script

```
title=${TITLE1}
## holds on to normal chars getting rid of the rest
title=${title//[^A-Za-z ]/}
```

Comment: Don't forget punctuation that you might want -- commas, apostrophes, periods, etc...

Answer (score 3):

This should get you pretty close:

```
newSongName=$(echo "$TITLE1" | tr -dc '[:print:]')
```

It tells `tr` to delete characters that are not in the `print` [class name](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). You could experiment with other character classes as needed.